# conception of a search method in Java

Tags: java, search, methods

I'm trying to write a method ("findEquipements") to find equipments by different criterias, but I have some problems.

1. if I append results, following each criteria, I will have the same equipment many times in my results.
2. I want to order the results, so that the first equipment in the result list will be the one with the most matched criterias.

Code:

```
public interface EquipementService {
    List<Equipement> findEquipements (SearchEquipement equipementSerach);
}
```

That was my interface,

```
public class SearchEquipement{

    private String marque ;
    private String type ;
    private Date dateAchat ;
    private String user ;

    public String getMarque(){
        return this.marque ;
    }

    public void setMarque(String marque){
        this.marque = marque ;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return this.type ;
    }

    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type ;
    }

    public String getUser(){
        return this.user ;
    }

    public void setUser(String user){
        this.user = user ;
    }

    public Date getDateAchat(){
        return this.dateAchat ;
    }

    public void setDateAchat(Date dateAchat){
        this.dateAchat = dateAchat ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Comparator and a sorted collection

Comment: @elaich You need add `equals` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. override hashcode and equals methods in the SearchEquipement class. Having the toString overridden is advisable for the purpose of debugging.
2. implement a comparable interface and override the compareTo method to order the results accordingly.
3. Use a Collections.sort() to properly sort-out the list items of the "List list"

supporting code -

```
 public class EquipmentComparable implements Comparator<SearchEquipement>{
  @Override
  public int compare(Equipement eq1, Equipement eq2) {
        //todo 
  }
 }


   List<Equipement> equipmentList = EquipementService.findEquipements  (equipementSerach);
   Collections.sort(equipmentList,new EquipmentComparable());
```